# Como capturar imagen de una camara ip con opencv c++?

Tags: c++, opencv

Tengo un sistema donde utilizo opencv y c++ para el conteo vehicular.
Capturando la imagen desde un vídeo por ejemplo

```
VideoCapture cap(video.pm4);
```

funciona bien, pero al momento de querer capturar la imagen desde un camara ip

```
VideoCapture cap("http://ip_address:port/");
```

no recibe nada. No se si la sintaxis es la correcta, o necesito algún tipo de complemento???

Gracias

Comment: "*al momento de querer capturar la imagen desde un camara ip se cae*" ¿qué significa que un código se caiga? ¿no te da error de compilación al pasar la url sin encerrarla entre comillas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para averiguar qué produce el error al abrir el input de la cámara deberías hacer algo así mejor:

```
VideoCapture cap;

cap.open("http://ipaddress:port/video?x.mjpeg");
if (!cap.isOpened())  //si ha fallado, sale
{
    cout << "No se puede abrir la camara" << endl;
    return -1;
}
```

Para capturar imágenes puedes usar un bucle de este tipo:

```
while (1)
{
    Mat imagen;

    bool ok= cap.read(imagen);
    if (!ok) //
    {
         cout << "No se pueden leer imagenes" << endl;
         break;
    }

    imshow("VideoIP", imagen);
}
```

Asegúrate de que la URL de la cámara es correcta.

> "http://ipaddress:port/video?x.mjpeg"

La clave del problema seguramente esté ahí.

Comment: Si lo tengo como el primer ejemplo que pusiste